# Does blinding a creature with the Gaze ability stop others from being affected by it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions

Does casting blindness on a Medusa (or other gaze using creature) stop their gaze attack?

Answer (score 19):

#### Yes, a blind Medusa cannot use its petrifying gaze.

The petrifying gaze of the Medusa says:

> When a creature that can see the medusa's eyes starts its turn within 30 feet of the Medusa, the medusa can force it to make a DC 14 Constitution saving throw if the medusa isn't incapacitated and **can see the creature**.

Same for basilisks. While their petrifying gaze is a bit different, they also have to see the target creature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61284/discussion-on-answer-by-thyzer-does-blinding-a-creature-with-the-gaze-ability-st).