# Does blinding a monster neutralize its petrifying gaze?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions

In a past quest I have awarded a Gem of Brighness as part of a treasure to my PCs. Now in the near future they may encounter some creatures with petrifying gaze, like a Basilisk or a Medusa.

The Gem of Brightness can blind those creatures; will this neutralize their petrifying gaze?

Comment: Duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102394/28591